# angular 2 router outlet on load

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have the following html element mainTemplate.html:

```
  <div id="content" class="row">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

app.routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import { BuySellComponent } from './buySell.component';

import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './can-deactivate-guard.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { SelectivePreloadingStrategy } from './selective-preloading-strategy';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent,

    }
    , {
        path: 'buysell',
        component: BuySellComponent,

    }

    , { path: '', redirectTo: '/buysell', pathMatch: 'full' }
];


//@NgModule({

//    exports: [
//        RouterModule
//    ],
//    providers: [
//        CanDeactivateGuard,
//        SelectivePreloadingStrategy
//    ]
//})
//export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const AppRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and the following html and typscript code to fill in the routher outlet

```
<div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare function testJs(): any;
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';   
declare function generateMap(): any;
//declare function jQuery(param: string): any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/mainTemplate.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    user: string;
    ngAfterViewInit () {
        generateMap();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('testing');
    }
    constructor() {
        testJs.prototype.testFunction();
        this.user = "asdf";
        var x = 90;
    }
}
```

generate map just merely using an openlayer map to load the map on an html div element with an id called "map".

however, during ngAfterViewInit  and ngOnInit the map element still does not exist.

what event is triggered when routher outlet finished loading its html element?

it is navigating to buySell.html and the  is in the buySell.html. buySell.html is the default route so it always loaded initally

Thanks.

Comment: are this `<div id="content" class="row">...` and this `<div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>` templates of some directives? do you use routing?]\

Comment: yes i use routing. I will edit the question and add some more code

Comment: what route do you navigate? what component does this template `<div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>` belong to?

Comment: it belongs to buySell which is the default route

Comment: try listening to `activate` event of `router-outlet`, but I'm not sure whether DOM is ready when it's emitted, or the component instance is simply activated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your `generateMap` be triggered on initialization of your AppComponent, you should move it to the `ngAfterViewInit` method of the component that's being routed to, instead.

Comment: yes I did that, the map div element still not detectedd

Comment: Ok, let's see if it's a timing issue, or something else...   Use setTimeout to delay the initialization (i.e. the generateMap call) by like 10 secs - by that time, all the routing should be finished. If you still don't get your map, then the problem isn't one of timing - it's something else that's wrong

Comment: yes i have used set time out but i think it's not a proper solution. thanks.

Comment: It's mostly to isolate the issue - since setTimout works, then it's definitely a timing issue. It's now just to figure exactly where the view stabilizes. You might need a setTimeout anyway, but with a much lower wait, just to let the event loop tick again

Comment: I have had the same problem...have you found a solution?
@snorkpete or jay?